# installing additional applications in Mandriva Linux

Tags: linux, mandriva

I just installed Mandriva Linux 2008 Spring. Everything is running smoothly and it can be started like Windows.

How can I install additional applications such as a VGA driver, or desktop effects (Fusion desktop)?

Comment: Hello LestiWulan, welcome to SU.  This question is too vague for us to be able to provide any help, perhaps have a go at [edit]ing it and provide specific details of the problem you are facing.

Comment: Why do you think you need a VGA driver? What hardware for, even? Have you seen RPMDrake, the package manager for Mandriva?